# Grub dual boot- debian wheezy (encrypted) with another OS

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning, debian, grub

I'm trying to dual boot debian wheezy (encrypted) with another OS (win7, uses 2 partitions)

In the wheezy installer I have created a bootable partition with 200M and then tried to made another crypto partition to hold my `/` + `/swap`. However the installer complains that I have **no root file system**.

What is the correct partitions that I need?

I notice when I use guided partitioning in another machine it sets it up the crypto one inside an extended partition. Is that how I need to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When partitioning the drive you must ensure you have "/" and "/swap" inside the entire encrypted partition. It seems like you did but you might of not wrote changes to the disk so the installer can recognize it. Either that or you are selecting the wrong partition.

Yes, you can use guided partitioning to make it a lot easier on yourself.