# Booting a second, encrypted Debian installation from Ubuntu grub command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, encryption, grub

I have a stable dual boot between Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1. I am installing a second flavor of Debian. It has three separate partitions: / is an encrypted luks volume located at (hd1,gpt9), /home is an encrypted luks volume located at (hd0, gpt3), /boot is non encrypted ext located at (hd1,gpt10). Both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 partitions are completely unencrypted. Only / and /home of the second Debian distro are encrypted. When I was installing the new debian distro (the third os), it failed to install its version of GRUB, although recognizing Ubuntu and Windows. After the failed GRUB install (Ubuntu and Windows intact and dual booting fine), it showed me a prompt that read as follows:

`You will need to boot manually with .vmlinuz kernel on partition /dev/mapper/sdb9_crypt and root=/dev/mapper/sdb9_crypt quiet initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz passed as a kernel argument`.

I ran the following commands in grub command line:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt9)

linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/sdb9_crypt initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz
```

This produces the error "unknown filesystem."

When I run these commands:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt10)

linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/sdb9_crypt initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz
```

This produces the error "file '/vmlinuz' not found"

I looked at the following forums, which got me going in the right direction but I'm still quite lost.
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=112803

[Grub dual boot- debian wheezy (encrypted) with another OS](https://superuser.com/questions/729136/grub-dual-boot-debian-wheezy-encrypted-with-another-os)

I'd like to try a command line boot before I modify grub.cfg. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally booted my image from GRUB 2.02 terminal. gpt10 is an unencrypted ext2 partition, containing the /boot files as this partition's root.

```
set root=(hd1,gpt10)
linux /vmlinuz-3.14-kali1-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/sdb9_crypt initrd=/boot/initrd.img-3.14-kali1-amd64
initrd /initrd.img-3.14-kali1-amd64
boot
```